# story-identification: fantasy story with physically weak protagonist that took place after nuclear winter

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I started reading this book when I was in either elementary school or middle school (anywhere from like 2004-2011) that I recall was too boring for me then but that I'm very interested in remembering now. Unfortunately I don't remember much about the book except these key details:

- I think it was written in the first person
- The main character was a boy/young man who was physically weak, too weak to be a knight, but was actually very skilled in military strategy
- He might have had asthma?
- The fantasy world they lived in was cold because it was actually Earth in the aftermath of a nuclear winter - this knowledge was not revealed at the end but was part of the book's exposition and not considered that big of a deal
- The main character might have been attending some sort of knighthood school or something in the beginning
- There may not have been any magic in this setting (but also there might have been and I don't remember)
- Eventually he has to go out on some sort of quest, but he is insecure about his poor physical prowess
- He had some sort of female friend who supported him
- The book cover was some sort of landscape that was mostly green and grey
- I don't think it was high fantasy - as far as I know, humans were the only race present

Sorry this is so incredibly vague! I've been racking my brain about this for hours now and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Was it actually fantasy, like with wizards, or was it just a basically feudal society?

Comment: I honestly can't remember if there were wizards or not, but I'd say I'm maybe 60% sure there weren't and it was kind of just a feudal society (except it was more futuristic than like medieval)

Comment: Possibly John Christopher's Sword of the Spirits trilogy? Take a look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161221/a-story-where-technology-is-forbidden-but-used-by-priests and linked answers.

Comment: Unfortunately after reading a preview of the beginning of the book I don't think it's this series.

Comment: It's too recent, but Joe Abercrombie's 'Shattered Sea' series is very similar, starting with 'Half a King'. An infirm but clever character scheming in a medieval-type post-apocalyptic world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds to me like *[Tomorrow's Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/743391.Tomorrow_s_Magic)*, originally published as two volumes, *Winter of Magic's Return* and *Tomorrow's Magic*.

Not first person, but most of the other points check out based on my own memory and the Kindle sample:

- Main character is Wellington "Welly" Jones, overweight and with poor eyesight.
- Vision and weight issues prevented Welly from attending the Cardiff Military Academy; as it is he is getting a general education at Llandoylan School.
- The Devastation 500 years before is discussed in the first chapter; the words "nuclear war" are used.
- There is magic in the setting, but that is not clear to the characters early on--if you didn't finish the book, you may not have seen much of it.
- Along with his best friend Heather and a boy who claims to be Merlin, Welly goes on a quest to find and bring back King Arthur.
- The cover shown on Goodreads includes a fair amount of green and grey.
- There may be some magical creatures lurking around the edges (it's been 30+ years since I read it myself), but the focus is definitely on humans.