# Post-apocalyptic novel called "After the Burning"(?)

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to locate a novel I read in the 1960s in paperback.

I believe the original title was (I think) *After the Burning*. The major theme was the collapse of human society and the hatred of science.

It was wonderfully well-written with irony and adventure - what you'd get if Heinlein wrote with Clarke's precision.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Burning_World_(novel)

Comment: The "hatred of science" part makes me think of Leigh Brackett's *The Long Tomorrow* (1955). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Tomorrow_(novel)

Answer (score 8):

Book two of the [Sword of the Spirits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Spirits) trilogy was titled [*Beyond the Burning Lands*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Spirits#Beyond_the_Burning_Lands).  Though it was published in 1971, at this remove that's pretty close to the 60s.

It meets your description of *collapse of human society and the hatred of science*:

> a post-apocalyptic future where, due to a worldwide ecological
> catastrophe, life has reverted to a militaristic, medieval setting of
> walled cities and perpetual warfare.... There are signs of the past
> existence of the modern world in the ruins of great cities and "high
> roads" which dot the harsh landscape, but the Seers have made the
> technology of the "ancients" anathema, and anyone dabbling in
> "Science" is immediately put to death.

[image: Beyond the Burning Lands - Cover]

Comment: Looks a good match to me.

Comment: Previously answered and accepted here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161221/a-story-where-technology-is-forbidden-but-used-by-priests and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220967/80s-90s-post-apocalyptic-novel-medieval-with-a-great-fire-and-a-mystic-sha and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156169/ya-fantasy-featuring-a-giant-blob-and-a-warrior/ and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103138/trilogy-of-books-set-in-the-future-with-knights-priests-and-dwarfs-and-a-r

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106805/looking-for-a-book-series-from-the-1960s-not-the-tripod-series/ and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/what-is-the-title-of-a-book-that-is-set-in-the-future-but-there-is-no-electrici/ (where the answer is not confirmed or accepted but is clearly correct)